# Error in JMX file generated from Selenium IDE

Tags: plugins, ide, jmeter

I generated some JMX script from Selenium IDE using Jmeter Plugin for Selenium.

I could able to generate JMX file from IDE and try to run the same in Jmeter. I am getting Unknown host exception in Jmeter.

Do I need to make some special setting in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea what `Jmeter Plugin for Selenium` is so I would suggest reach out to this plugin developers.

In regards to converting Selenium tests into JMeter, you can just record the test while it is running in the IDE via JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

Selenium IDE plugin should respect [Firefox Proxy Settings](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/advanced-panel-settings-in-firefox#w_connection) so when you run your test in it JMeter will capture the relevant requests and store them in form of [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.

---

Another option is using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool which has [Proxy2JMX](http://gettaurus.org/docs/Proxy2JMX/) module allowing conversion of Selenium tests into JMeter .jmx test scripts, as a bonus you will get automatic correlation of dynamic parameters, it means you won't have to work them arround using post-processors, Taurus will do this for you. See [How to Convert Selenium Scripts into the JMX Converter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter) article for more details.